# Returning variables from functions containing if elif else statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to check that `raw_input` is a choice of 1 of three options using the following code:

```
def selectDiff():
    upperbound = 0
    difficulty = ['easy', 'medium', 'hard']
    diff = raw_input(' or '.join(difficulty)).lower()
    if diff in difficulty:
        if diff == 'easy':
            upperbound = 20

        elif diff == 'medium':
            upperbound = 25

        elif diff == 'hard':
            upperbound = 30

    else:
        print "Please select easy, medium or hard\n"
        selectDiff()

    return upperbound
```

If the user enters a value from the difficulty list `['easy','medium','hard']` the function works as I'd like it to, but if the user enters value not contained in the list first, when they finally enter a value found in the list, the variable `upperbound` is return as 0. I've tried moving the return statement around but either the result is the same or I get an error due to referring to a variable before it's been declined.

Is it possible to alter my approach to produce the desired behaviour or should I use another approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `while` loop which keeps taking input until the user enters the correct input.

```
 def selectDiff():
    difficulty = ['easy', 'medium', 'hard']
    while True:
        diff = raw_input('easy, medium or hard').lower()
        if diff in difficulty:
            if diff == 'easy':
                return 20   
            elif diff == 'medium':
                return 25   
            elif diff == 'hard':
                return  30    
        else:
            print "Please select easy, medium or hard\n"
```

Answer (score 5):

I agree that using a loop probably makes more sense here, but if you want to keep using recursion, simply assign `upperbound` to the result of the inner `selectDiff`.

```
def selectDiff():
    difficulty = ['easy', 'medium', 'hard']
    diff = raw_input(' or '.join(difficulty)).lower()

    if diff in difficulty:
        if diff == 'easy':
            upperbound = 20
        elif diff == 'medium':
            upperbound = 25
        elif diff == 'hard':
            upperbound = 30
    else:
        print "Please select easy, medium or hard\n"
        upperbound = selectDiff()  # Use the returned value

    return upperbound
```

On a side note, you could also use a `dict` to replace the `elif` chain and make it a bit easier to extend.

```
def selectDiff():
    difficulty = {
        'easy': 20, 
        'medium': 25, 
        'hard': 30,
    }

    diff = raw_input(' or '.join(difficulty)).lower()
    try:
        return difficulty[diff]
    except KeyError:
        print "Please select easy, medium or hard\n"
        return selectDiff()
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `selectDiff()` inside itself and then ignoring the return value. You would be better off using a loop instead of an unlimited recursion.

Like this for instance:

```
def selectDiff():
    while True:
        diff = raw_input('easy, medium or hard').lower()
        if diff=='easy':
            return 20
        if diff=='medium':
            return 25
        if diff=='hard':
            return 30
        print "Please select easy, medium or hard\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you were hoping to do here is make `upperbound` a dynamically-scoped closure variable, even though you probably have no idea what those words mean. That won't work because Python doesn't do dynamic scoping (nor do most other modern languages), and before 3.x Python closure variables don't work if you assign to them.

However, you can *simulate* the scoping you want by carefully using a global variable, or (better) a lexically-scoped variable, and you can simulate assignment by storing the variable inside another mutable variable. So:

```
def selectDiff():
    upperbound = [0]

    def realSelectDiff():
        difficulty = ['easy', 'medium', 'hard']
        diff = raw_input(' or '.join(difficulty)).lower()
        if diff in difficulty:
            if diff == 'easy':
                upperbound[0] = 20

            elif diff == 'medium':
                upperbound[0] = 25

            elif diff == 'hard':
                upperbound[0] = 30

        else:
            print "Please select easy, medium or hard\n"
            realSelectDiff()

    realSelectDiff()
    return upperbound[0]
```

Now, each call to `realSelectDiff` isn't setting its own local copy of `upperbound`, they're all setting the outer `selectDiff`'s copy of the `upperbound` value.

All that being said, this is almost never a good idea. If you want to use recursion, you almost always want to pass values up the stack, and you don't want to use recursion to simulate looping in the first place. But it's worth understanding how this works.

Comment: much better simpler answer exists - like using either while, or just straight recursion - this is just plain complex for no obvious reason.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66: This answers the OP's question, and shows that it is possible to do what he wants to do—and also shows that it's not easy, which shows _why_ he shouldn't want to do it this way. Just giving him different code and saying "do this instead" doesn't help him learn, and lying and saying "It's not possible" when it is helps even less.